# Trying to uninstall vmware packages but get 'unmet dependencies' error

Tags: apt, package-management, vmware

So when I do `dpkg --get-selections | grep vmware` I get...

```
vmware-tools-core               install
vmware-tools-esx-nox                install
vmware-tools-foundation             install
vmware-tools-guestlib               purge
vmware-tools-libraries-nox          install
vmware-tools-plugins-autoupgrade        install
vmware-tools-plugins-deploypkg          install
vmware-tools-plugins-guestinfo          install
vmware-tools-plugins-hgfsserver         install
vmware-tools-plugins-powerops           install
vmware-tools-plugins-timesync           install
vmware-tools-plugins-vix            install
vmware-tools-plugins-vmbackup           install
vmware-tools-services               install
```

I would like to remove these. So for instance when I do...

```
sudo apt-get -f remove vmware-tools-core
```

I get...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-virtual : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-57-virtual but it is not going to be installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.56.66) but 3.2.0.57.68 is to be installed
 vmware-tools-esx-nox : Depends: vmware-tools-core (>= 9.0.5) but it is not going to be installed
 vmware-tools-plugins-autoupgrade : Depends: vmware-tools-core-9.0.5
 vmware-tools-plugins-deploypkg : Depends: vmware-tools-core-9.0.5
 vmware-tools-plugins-guestinfo : Depends: vmware-tools-core-9.0.5
 vmware-tools-plugins-hgfsserver : Depends: vmware-tools-core-9.0.5
 vmware-tools-plugins-powerops : Depends: vmware-tools-core-9.0.5
 vmware-tools-plugins-timesync : Depends: vmware-tools-core-9.0.5
 vmware-tools-plugins-vix : Depends: vmware-tools-core-9.0.5
 vmware-tools-plugins-vmbackup : Depends: vmware-tools-core-9.0.5
 vmware-tools-services : Depends: vmware-tools-core-9.0.5
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I run `apt-get -f install` I get...

```
After this operation, 36.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 464964 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-57-virtual (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-57-virtual_3.2.0-57.87_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-57-virtual_3.2.0-57.87_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/abi-3.2.0-57-virtual': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-57-virtual /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-virtual
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-57-virtual /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-virtual
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-57-virtual_3.2.0-57.87_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
johnmlocklear@vweb-dev:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
```

Here is the output of dpkg -l 'linux*' http://pastie.org/8528966

My goal is to remove the vmware tools packages. Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes dual. First, you have `/boot` full of scrub. You need to scrub it! Run `dpkg -l 'linux*'` and remove the old non-used kernels. That will solve the `sudo apt-get -f install` problem. The next one you need to remove all the packages in one swoop:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-server linux-server linux-image-3.2.0-48-virtual linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic linux-image-3.2.0-51-virtual  linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic linux-image-3.2.0-52-virtual linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic linux-image-3.2.0-53-virtual linux-image-3.2.0-56-generic linux-image-3.2.0-56-virtual
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove  vmware-tools-esx-nox vmware-tools-services vmware-tools-plugins-* vmware-tools-core
sudo apt-get install linux-server linux-headers-server
```

That should solve your problem

Comment: OK, I am trying to get rid of images using the script from this post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1435818. Each image gives me this error http://pastie.org/8528865. Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: @Lumbee is there a problem specifying them manually? Like `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-version-generic`? Why use the script? Also to see if there's indeed a problem you may want to edit your question and add the output of `dpkg -l 'linux*'` and `sudo apt-get cache`.

Comment: When I do  sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.2.0-54-gen I get http://pastie.org/8528960

Comment: @Lumbee the output still lacks. Where is `sudo apt-get check` and `dpkg -l 'linux*'`?

Comment: I need the complete package list. Please, do not remove anything of the information asked I need to know exactly all the packages that you have installed.

Comment: If possible use http://paste.ubuntu.com instead

Comment: OK, heres the complete list...http://paste.ubuntu.com/6525390/

Comment: @Lumbee edited.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and I found some useful information on this [site](http://baal-ammon.livejournal.com/279067.html)  (it's in french).

When I did a `di -f` command I found that all the i-nodes where being used (100%, please correct me if I'm saying something wrong).

So you should try emptying `/usr/src` and see if it works.

EDIT: just tested this solution and it worked, I deleted some folders in `/urs/src` and then I could execute the `apt-get -f install` command.

Comment: This can potentially damage your system as none apt or dpkg knows that the files is not longer there.